# create and show one use only dialog, constructed based on global state.

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have a plugin which need to show a (Modal) dialog each time the user double click on a word.

Detecting double click is no problem, but the exact fields/values in the dialog depends on exactly which word the user clicked on, and some mutable global state. So I can't create the dialog until the moment before I need to show it. And here is the problem: How do I do that?

Right now I use this code:

```
var dialogName="uniqueDialog" + counter++;
CKEDITOR.dialog.add(dialogName,function(editor) {
     // Creating dialog here.
    });
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.openDialog(dialogName);
```

This works, but having to add a uniquely named dialog, just to show it once and then newer use it again seems really really wrong. Also I fear this will keep using resources since the dialogs are newer removed(I could not find any remove method).

So my question is: Is there a better way to dynamical create and show a "one use" dialog?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

If bootstrap is not allowed then maybe an addFrame version of the dialog is acceptable. This could then refer to a html file that can load from parameters.

NB: The plunkr only works, if you fork and edit it, otherwise it will give you a 404 for the template.

Here is a quick plunkr:

[plunky](https://plnkr.co/edit/BCzvK8)

And here is the plugin in question:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'insertVariable', {
   requires: ['iframedialog'],
  icons: 'insertvariable',
  init: function( editor ) {

    editor.addCommand( 'varDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'varDialog' ) );

    CKEDITOR.dialog.addIframe('varDialog','varDialog','sample.html?var='+item,500,400);

    editor.ui.addButton( 'insertVariable', {
      label: 'Insert Variable',
      command: 'varDialog',
      icon: this.path + '<insert gif>'
    });

  }
});
```

Obviously you are not creating dialogs anymore with different content, but you are referring to another piece of html, that can change. I've kept the bootstrap thing in there as well for reference.

I made one final edit, that will show the current contents. So I think that is roughly what you want. Check it out.

**Previous Answer**

If you are prepared to use bootstrap, then you can do no worse than check out their modal dialog, which can be just be shown and hidden at will.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

It's simple and cuts down any need to keep creating your own dialog. The dialog won't be one use type, but you will set the defaults as necessary. The varying content link is here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

That would be the quickest way to get this going. It all depends on whether you want to use this framework. As CKEDITOR is already using JQuery it is an option worth considering.

Comment: Thanks but I really can't use bootstrap. I am using GWT to do all the development of my webapp, including writing all ckeditor plugins in java.